# Не работает react-router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Не работает react-router 4.3.1, когда пытаюсь на зайти на `/one` или на `/two`
(версия react 16.4.2)

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';


const One = () => (
  <p>
    "One"
  </p>
);

const Two = () => (
  <p>
    "Two"
  </p>
);

const Three = () => (
  <p>
    "Three"
  </p>
);

ReactDOM.render(
  
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Three>
        <Switch>
          <Route path='/one' component={One} /> 
          <Route path='/two' component={Two} />        
        </Switch>
      </Three>
    </BrowserRouter>
 ,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.4.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.4.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

А вот так вот заработало:
Почему так?

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';


const One = () => (
  <p>
    "One"
  </p>
);

const Two = () => (
  <p>
    "Two"
  </p>
);

const Three = () => (
  <p>
    "Three"
    <Switch>
          <Route path='/one' component={One} /> 
          <Route path='/two' component={Two} />        
    </Switch>
  </p>
);

ReactDOM.render(
  
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Three/>

      
    </BrowserRouter>
 ,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.4.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.4.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0):

В вашем случае

```
 <Three> // оборачивающая компонента
    // children
  </Three>
```

Если вы перепишете

```
const Three = ({children}) => (
  <p>
    {children}
  </p>
);
```

То все будет работать

Тут можно [почитать](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#children-in-jsx)

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте обернуть Route-ы в тег `<Routes></Routes>`

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter, Switch, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';


    const One = () => (
      <p>
        "One"
      </p>
    );
    
    const Two = () => (
      <p>
        "Two"
      </p>
    );
    
    const Three = () => (
      <p>
        "Three"
      </p>
    );
    
    ReactDOM.render(
      
        <BrowserRouter>
          <Three>
            <Switch>
              <Routes>
                  <Route path='/one' component={One} /> 
                  <Route path='/two' component={Two} /> 
              </Routes>       
            </Switch>
          </Three>
        </BrowserRouter>
     ,
      document.getElementById('root')
    );
```